# CruiseControl.NET send mail with fix list on build?

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I was wondering if it is possible if I could include a Fix List with my deployment build email notification,what I was expecting is I would add the latest changes to a text file stored in a directory and CruiseControl.NET would pick it from there and send along with the email.Anybody has any similar solutions, or how did you do it? Any samples or links?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first question is whether you do continuous integration (CI) builds or just periodical builds? In case it is CI, have you tried writing this fix list into the check-in comment of your version control system? CCNet shows this comment as part of the build report (and email notification).

UPDATE: the other option I see is to write your own CCNet plugin for this. It shouldn't be too hard. As a reference on writing CCNet plugins you can use my own [BrekiLabeller](http://sourceforge.net/projects/brekiccnetutils/) plugin.

Comment: I have both build, I wanted this on my "deployment" builds not on "ci" builds.I use sourcegear so you think if I add comments while I check in the fixes it should work?

Comment: I haven't used sourcegear, so I cannot guarantee. The best thing would be to try it out. I added another option in the answer abovce.